# Finding users connected to same wireless network

Tags: php, authentication

All,

I wanted to programmatically find out how to check if a remote access to my website is associated with only my wireless network. I know this might not be needed by having it our the intranet. But I have to add this feature to my application and the firm needs that. I am using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

**What you have:**

- IP of remote user

**What you need:**

- List of IP addresses or netblocks associated with each of your corporate wireless networks

**Solution:**

- Check the user's IP to see if it's in the list.

---

You'll need to speak with whomever maintains your network to see if they can give you a way to query for the second piece of information (List of IP addresses/netblocks).

Comment: Can I use the IP address of user to derive anything that would help me? I am sorry but am not good at all with networking!

Comment: No, nothing about the IP address inherently means that it's on a wireless network. Often, the same DHCP server hands out IP addresses to wired and wireless clients. You need to talk to your network admin to help you determine #2 in the above list.

Answer (score -2):

Your wireless network is encompassed in a subnet with **only one** external IP. You could log it with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. Any machine in the subnet you're on will appear with that **same IP**. There is no way I know of to differentiate between machines on the same subnet but different wireless access points. I don't believe it should be possible, but the subnet is probably enough for you.

**Beware** that if the internet connection this subnet uses eventually gets a different IP address from the ISP (**extremely likely**), you will start seeing that different IP.

Hope that's enough for you to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Just because your wireless network only has one external IP address doesn't mean that all do.